# Compare Long to String

Tags: jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

In JPQL in a where condition I want to do:

```
book.id like lower(:search)
```

The problem: `book.id` is a `Long` but the `:search` parameter is a String. Will the above just work the way it is or do I need to explicitly convert `book.id` to `String` and if that's the case, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would convert `:search` parameter to `Long` and change the query condition to:

```
book.id = :search
```

then

```
List<Books> books = em.createQuery("... WHERE book.id = :search")
                      .setParameter("search", Long.valueOf(strSearch))
                      .getResultList();
```

In general processing numbers is faster than strings.

Comment: That wouldn't work because in my case the `:search` parameter is not only used to compare to that `id` but also to the title(users can search for id or title).

Comment: Hmmm, such a case wasn't part of the initial question ;). If you need to compare `:search` with a title string then `LIKE` is the right choice. Anyway it would be helpful to update the question with the full query definition (even pseudocode) for better understanding the idea behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CAST statement in JPQL like:

```
CAST(book.id AS string) LIKE lower(:search)
```

But with this solution you won't be able to use any index on the book.id column.